# Защитить <html> от remove()

Tags: javascript, html

У меня есть html страница со скриптом следующего содержания -

`document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].remove();`

Естественно каждый раз при загрузке страницы у меня удаляется главный html элемент. Как я могу открыть страницу в браузере, минуя этот скрипт, но выполняя все остальные? Страница лежит на чужом сервере, просто удалить скрипт я не могу. Через отладчик хрома тоже не выходит, нельзя изменять выполняемый код.

Comment: Выключите в браузере js

Comment: @MaximPoddubny мне нужно, чтобы другие скрипты выполнялись, читайте   внимательнее задачу.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ничего непонятно. Сервер чужой, а что Ваше?

Сначала воспроизведем поведение, которое Вы наблюдаете. `div`-а со словом "test" не наблюдaется:

```js
document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].remove();
```

```html
<div>test</div>
```

Теперь "врежемся" в метод документа, чтобы перехватить выбор по тэгу:

```js
var oldGetByTag = document.getElementsByTagName.bind(document);
document.getElementsByTagName = function(tag) {
  console.log(tag);
  if (tag == 'html') {
    return [document.createElement("div")];
  }
  return oldGetByTag(tag);
};

console.log(document.getElementsByTagName('html'));
document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].remove();
```

```html
<div>test</div>
```

Но это я, конечно, намудрил. Можно проще:

```js
document.querySelector("html").remove = function() {
  console.log("do nothing");
}

document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].remove();
```

```html
<div>test</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
HTMLHtmlElement.prototype.remove = function () {}
```